# DJango Persist session across 2 forms

Tags: python, django, forms, session

I am trying to pass data (eventually dictionary, for testing I am passing a dummy variable) from one form to another. Its a multi step form.
For this I am using request.session object. However when after Post from the first form when I reach second form the session data is None and when I printed the session key it seems that it has changed. I am using default db based session.
My overall aim to pass data from form1 to form2. If there are any other suggestion for doing that I am willing to try them out as well.

Reference Docs - 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/
http://gregblogs.com/dealing-with-forms-a-beginners-look-into-django-forms-and-sessions/

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.sessions',
...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
]
```

Views.py

```
def step1(request):
form = UploadPickFileForm(request.POST)
# Create form instance

print "Session{}".format(request.session._get_session_key())
if request.method == 'POST':
    initial = {'text':request.session.get('text', None)}
    form = UploadPickFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial = initial)
    if form.is_valid():
        action = form.cleaned_data.get('action')
        uploaded_file = form.cleaned_data.get('file')
        extractor = get_upload_extractor_for_source(form.cleaned_data.get('source'))
        print "Action{}".format(action)
        if action == INGEST_ACTION:
            uploaded_file = form.cleaned_data.get('file')
            try:
                ingestable_upload = extractor.get_ingestable_upload(uploaded_file)
                context = {'ingestable_upload': ingestable_upload}
            except ParseError as e:
                return self.show_error(e)

            request.session['text'] = form.cleaned_data.get('action')
            tt = request.session.get('text', None)
            request.session.modified = True # just to force session save
            print "Session data{}".format(tt)               
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('step2'))
        else:
            form = UploadPickFileForm()
    else:
        print "form is INVALID {}".format(form.errors) 

return render(request,'step1.html', {'form':form})

def step2(request):    
    print "Session{}".format(request.session._get_session_key())
    form = MappedReleaseTitleForm(request.POST)  
    formset_class = formset_factory(MappedReleaseTitleForm, extra =0)
    tt = request.session.get('text', None)
    print "Session data{}".format(tt)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset =  formset_class(data,initial=[{'title':'HHHH'}])
        if formset.is_valid():
            data = formset.cleaned_data
            print "data is {}".format(data)        
    return render (request, 'step2.html', {'form':formset_class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Might django-formtools (https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) be a good choice?  In particular, the form wizard which "splits forms across multiple Web pages".

It might help solve your problem without you having to write it from scratch!

Comment: This answer could be improved by elaborating on how solves the problem that is being asked.